# ASP.NET First time accessing DB error

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, sql-server-2008-r2

in my app in `Application_Start()` I load some static data from DB for further use. But the problem is that when the server is idle for example for one day,then the first request to Db is unsuccessful and returns this error:

```
The client was unable to establish a connection because of an error during connection initialization process before login.
Possible causes include the following:
the client tried to connect to an unsupported version of SQL Server;
the server was too busy to accept new connections;
or there was a resource limitation (insufficient memory or maximum allowed connections) on the server.

(provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)
```

Then after a refresh, everything works fine. So any idea? And why is `Application_Start()` called every day? I thought that its only called when the app is requested first time and then only after restarting it from IIS.

EDIT:
I am using SQL server 2008R2 express
There shouldn't be problem in my code I think, but her it is:

```
    public static SqlConnection sqlCon()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString);             
    }
public void fillFromDB()                                      
    {
        SqlConnection con = defVal.sqlCon();
        SqlCommand cmd_getK = new SqlCommand("usp_getAllKomponenty", con);
        cmd_getK.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd_getK.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    this.adKomp(reader[0].ToString(), new elisKomponent(reader[0].ToString(), reader[1].ToString(), new date(Convert.ToInt32(reader[2]))));
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("Chyba při čtení komponenty databáze"+e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which edition of sql server are you using?

Comment: Where is the code that you use to collect this data? It feels like you have an instance of a `SqlConnection` that you're storing **(which you should not be doing)** and trying to leverage it again later. *Always create new and properly dispose of `SqlConnection` objects.*

Comment: look up the "using" statement.  You'll want to go that way...so you get IDispose.Dispose being called.  Using your connections and then dispose of them...........don't try to outthink it...let connection pooling handle the voodoo for you...esp on a asp.net website.

Comment: I tried the using statement and enabled pooling but nothing has changed

Answer (score 1):

Try the more/most specific type of connection string.

IP Address, Port Number.  Network-Protocol.

```
Data Source=192.168.1.333,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;
User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

That could help......as it will get rid of a few "resolving" checks.

Comment: The connection string looks like this <add name="Test" connectionString="Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=DB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user;Password=pasword" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />  But That shouldn't be the prblem, it's like the server was stuck when I am trying to access it for the first time, but it isn't. Once I tride to login to the server throught my remote destkop right in the time, my app was tryiing to connect, and I was able to, but the app stil wasn't

Comment: When you put a servername in, it has to be resolved.  When you don't put the port number in, it has to figure out the port number.  When you don't specify the network protocol, it uses the default one in your registry.  It's a cheap attempt to just try and alter the connection string.  I'm not saying your connection string is wrong, I'm saying you can make an attempt to make it more-specific as an attempt.